# C: How can i write ( x -> x- > x ) using (.) dot operator

Tags: c, pointers

Regarding structs and pointers, how can I write this expression `x->x->x` using the dot operator?

Using arrow operator: `x->x->x` I easily acces third element. Using dot operator : `(*x).x` How can I acces the third element using the dot operator?

I know arrow operator is a shortcut for the dot operator, so it should be possible to reach third element using dot operator? I could use a variable:

```
struct node *var
var = (*ptr).next
(*var).x = some value
```

It really annoys me. Have been looking in text book and everywhere on internet and can't find an answer.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Doing dereferencing of pointers like this without checking validity of the middle pointer will easily result in unwitting memory faults in a program. The cause would be a NULL value in the intermediary pointer(s) (in your case value of next) and that may yield the next question of "Why is my program crashing" :-)

Comment: Why Why WHYYYYYYY! Why people want to do this kind of ugly stuff!

Answer (score 7):

Well `x -> x` is equivalent to `(*x).x` So you just do that twice:

```
(*(*x).x).x
```

`.` binds tighter that unary `*` so the precedence works. If you were feeling paranoid you could do:

```
(*((*x).x)).x
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that `x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y`, then applying that rule twice:

```
x->x->x;
(*x).x->x;
(*(*x).x).x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would *never* want to do this in real life, but

```
(*p1).x
```

is the member `x` in the object pointed to by `p1`;

```
(*((*p1).p2)).y
```

is the member `y` in the object pointed to by `p2` which is a member in the object pointed to by `p1`, and

```
(*((*((*p1).p2)).p3).z
```

is the member `z` in the object pointed to by `p3`, which is a member in the object pointed to by `p2`, which is a member in the object pointed to by `p1`.

It's entirely possible that this could be done with fewer parentheses, but they definitely help with understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*(*x).x).x
```

But why, oh why????

Answer (score 1):

Nested dereferencing ...

```
(*(*x).x).x
```

I *Think* that gets you there. As to why you'd want to do such a thing ... ugly, ugly, ugly.

Comment: I know it's ugly, but I just wanted to know to do it. Since my text book in school doesnt tell it :)

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Ah. Removed my downvote if it was just for 'educational purposes'. :)